# validation before ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How do i introduce validation before **remote_form_for** submits?

I have javascript function called **validateForm()**. I am able to call it before the AJAX request process. I tried to use **return false** and **event.preventDefault**. But there seems to be no effect. Here is what my code looks like

```
<% remote_form_for :customer, :update =>"uxScreenLoaderDiv", :url => {:action => "login", :controller => "site"},  :onsubmit => "validateForm(event)" do |f| %>
    User name : <%= f.text_field "uxUserName", :class => "TextBox", :style => "width:100px;" %>&nbsp;*
    &nbsp;Password : <%= f.password_field "uxPassword", :class => "TextBox", :style => "width:100px;" %>&nbsp;*
    <%= f.submit "Go!", :class => "Button-Simple", :id => "uxSubmitButton" %>   
<% end %>
```

the javascript function is simple as follows

```
function validateForm(event){
   return false;
   //event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<% remote_form_for :customer, :update =>"uxScreenLoaderDiv", :url => {:action => "login", :controller => "site"}, :html => {:id => "uxLoginForm"}, :onsubmit => "return validateForm(event)" do |f| %>
```

i.e. change

```
 :onsubmit => "validateForm(event)
```

to

```
 :onsubmit => "return validateForm(event)
```

EDITED it should be

```
<% remote_form_for :customer, :update =>"uxScreenLoaderDiv", 
         :url => {:action => "login", :controller => "site"}, 
         :html => {:id => "uxLoginForm", :onsubmit => "return validateForm(event)"} 
         do |f|
 %>
```

EDITED AGAIN

WHY don't you use :condition for it? something like following

```
<% remote_form_for :customer, :update =>"uxScreenLoaderDiv", 
         :url => {:action => "login", :controller => "site"}, 
         :html => {:id => "uxLoginForm"},
         :condition=>"validateForm(event)!=false"
         do |f|
 %>
```

Comment: using return validateForm(event) only makes it a usual form and makes the form behaving with ajax request

Comment: please check my "EDITED AGAIN" and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like onSubmit="return validateForm(this)" or thereabouts. Then if the validation returns false (because it failed validation) the form should not submit.

Comment: i tried it earlier.. it has a problem... if the return value is true the form submits directly and is no longer an AJAX request

Comment: If you are just trying to do a pure AJAX request, a submit button is unnecessary. You can just use a plain "button" type input like 
<input type="button" id="blah" /> and use an onClick handler.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check LIvevalidation plugin (http://github.com/augustl/live-validations) which you can you to do Ajax  with active record validations

And its always good to have non-ajax validations also (even though you use ajax validations) as ajax will not work in javascript disable browser

cheers,
sameera

Comment: Good tip: i am already using the jquery.validate plugin for this; but had to manually copy my validations.